# Atom editor Package installation error

Tags: npm, editor, atom-editor

I got an error when i install packages in Atom

```
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Jarvis\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.5.3\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Jarvis\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.5.3\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "C:\\Users\\Jarvis\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\Jarvis\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\Jarvis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d-116128-3752-1lwywgv\\package.tgz" "--target=0.34.5" "--arch=ia32"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Jarvis\.atom\.apm\nopt\3.0.6\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Jarvis\.atom\.apm\nopt\3.0.6\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
```

I am trying to install lots of packages in atom Editor but i got above error.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the `C:\Users\Jarvis\.atom\.apm\nopt\3.0.6\package\package.json` with Notpad++ ( or any other editor your choice - just don't do it in atom, it will crash, at least in Version 1.6.2 it did for me ) and look for the non printable characters. You will see that the file contain a lot of `NUL`. I had the same error suddenly one day, when trying to install updates for my packages.

Here is what i did to resolve the error. Be warned however that you have to install all packages again. Personally i use sync-settings (which backups my packages etc.), so it was no big deal for me.

- Delete the entire C:\Users\Jarvis.atom\packages folder
- Delete the entier C:\Users\Jarvis.atom.apm folder
- Reinstall all packages (.apm folders will then installed automatically)

It can be hard to delete those folders because of the Path too long restriction. In this case there helps a Stackexchange answer: [How to delete a file in Windows with a too long filename?](https://superuser.com/a/467814)